# Calling function within traditional way gives good result, calling function by gui tkinter throw an exception

Tags: python, tkinter

I got weird problem. Im bulding GUI with `tkinter` for my vending machine. 
Mya items has got ID from 30 to 50. I would like to get the price of given ID by calling `getPriceOfGivenID` method. I mean, if I press button 3 + 1, I will get 31 right, so I want to get ID of 31 item by clicking `proceed` button.  Unfortunately it throws exception do not know why. If I call the function from the same file, from the `VendingMachine.py` it gives me good result. Why is that?

`VendingMachine.py`

```
from Coin import Coin
from Bank import Bank
from Item import Item
from decimal import *
from Automat import Automat
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

x1 = Coin(Decimal("0.01"))
x2 = Coin(Decimal("0.02"))
x3 = Coin(Decimal("0.05"))
x4 = Coin(Decimal("0.1"))
x5 = Coin(Decimal("0.2"))
x6 = Coin(Decimal("0.5"))
x7 = Coin(Decimal("1"))
x8 = Coin(Decimal("2"))
x9 = Coin(Decimal("5"))
listOfCoins = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9]

bank = Bank()
for x in range(15):
    for i in listOfCoins:
        bank.addMoney(i)
Cola = Item(2) #cola prize is 2
Water = Item(1) #water prize is 1 etc.
Pepsi = Item(0.5)
SparklingWater = Item(0.25)
Cola2 = Item(1.3)
Cola3 = Item(2.5)
Cola4 = Item(2.45)
Cola5 = Item(3)
container = Automat(bank)
listOfItems = [Cola, Cola2, Cola3, Cola4, Cola5, Water, Pepsi, SparklingWater]

for i in listOfItems:
    container.add_object(i)

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('600x500')
gui.title("Vending Machine")

gui.configure(background="light green")
expression = ""
equation = StringVar()
expression_field = Entry(gui, textvariable=equation)
expression_field.grid(row=8, columnspan=4, ipadx=70)
equation.set('enter number of item')

labelOne = ttk.Label(gui, text='')
labelOne.grid(column=1, row=12)

labelTwo = ttk.Label(gui, text='')
labelTwo.grid(column=1, row=18)


def dropCoin(wartosc):
    labelTwo.configure(text='Wrzucono: {0:0.2f}'.format(container.howManyCoinsWereDropped(wartosc)))


def getPriceOfGivenID():
    a = equation.get()
    print(a) # it gives good result, for example 30
    labelOne.configure(text='You need to give: ' + container.find_price_of_given_id(a)) # it throws an exception

print(container.find_price_of_given_id(31)) # it gives good result 

# Function to update expressiom
# in the text entry box
def press(num):
    global expression
    expression = expression + str(num)
    equation.set(expression)
    return expression


##### BUTTONS
button1 = Button(gui, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(1), height=1, width=7)
button1.grid(row=2, column=0)

button2 = Button(gui, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(2), height=1, width=7)
button2.grid(row=2, column=1)

button3 = Button(gui, text=' 3 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(3), height=1, width=7)
button3.grid(row=2, column=2)

button4 = Button(gui, text=' 4 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(4), height=1, width=7)
button4.grid(row=3, column=0)

button5 = Button(gui, text=' 5 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(5), height=1, width=7)
button5.grid(row=3, column=1)

button6 = Button(gui, text=' 6 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(6), height=1, width=7)
button6.grid(row=3, column=2)

button7 = Button(gui, text=' 7 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(7), height=1, width=7)
button7.grid(row=4, column=0)

button8 = Button(gui, text=' 8 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(8), height=1, width=7)
button8.grid(row=4, column=1)

button9 = Button(gui, text=' 9 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(9), height=1, width=7)
button9.grid(row=4, column=2)

button0 = Button(gui, text=' 0 ', fg='black', bg='red',
                 command=lambda: press(0), height=1, width=7)
button0.grid(row=5, column=1)


mainframe = ttk.Frame(gui)

gui.mainloop()
```

`Automat.py`

```
from Item import Item
from NoItemException import NoItemException
from Bank import Bank
from Coin import Coin
from decimal import *

class Automat:
    item_id = 30

    def __init__(self, _bank, objects=None):
        self.bank = _bank
        if objects is None:
            objects = {}
        self.objects = objects
        self._purchaseItemBank = []

    def add_object(self, obj: Item):
        id_to_assign = Automat.item_id
        self.objects.update({id_to_assign: obj})
        Automat.item_id = Automat.item_id + 1
        return id_to_assign

    def get_length(self):
        return len(self.objects)

    def find_price_of_given_id(self, item_id):
        print(item_id) #it gives good passed item_id
        if self.objects.get(item_id) is not None: #throw an exception if call from gui app, if call within normal way print(container.find_price_of_given_id(31)) gives good result
            return self.objects.get(item_id).get_price()
        else:
            raise NoItemException

    def find_amount_of_given_id(self, item_id):
        if self.objects.get(item_id) is not None:
            return self.objects.get(item_id).get_amount()
        else:
            raise NoItemException
```

If I make something like this at `VendingMachine.py`

```py
print(container.find_price_of_given_id(31))
```

then I get good result.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/vending-machine/VendingMachine.py", line 117, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: getPriceOfGivenID(), height=1, width=7)
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/vending-machine/VendingMachine.py", line 62, in getPriceOfGivenID
    labelOne.configure(text='Musisz wrzucić: ' + container.find_price_of_given_id(a))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\vending-machine\Automat.py", line 32, in find_price_of_given_id
    raise NoItemException
NoItemException.NoItemException
```

I paste also `Item.py`, do not know if needed, but...:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, price, amount=5):
        self.amount = amount
        self.price = price

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price

    def get_amount(self):
        return self.amount

    def decrease(self):
        self.amount -= 1

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.amount} @ {self.price}"
```

Comment: Check if you are looking up using `str` while your dictionary keys are `int`. Try doing something like `self.objects.get(int(item_id))`.

Comment: where is "proceed button" code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a case of mismatching types. In particular, your dictionary `objects` inside the `Automat` class uses `int` as keys. When you do the lookup later on, instead, you use the value passed in by `equation.get()`. Now, `equation` is a `StringVar` which returns `str` when you do a `get()` on it.

Note that in python you can have dictionaries with keys as either number or strings, but they are *different* keys:

```
{'1': 'this key is a string', 1: 'this key is an int'}
```

Few different ways to go for a fix, but essentially you need to make sure that the lookup is performed using `int`.

One example would be:

```
def getPriceOfGivenID():
    a = int(equation.get())
    ... # rest of your core
```

Or, you could convert inside both `find_price_of_given_id` and `find_amount_of_given_id`, or change the `add_object` method and define keys as `str`.

Comment: You are god! Thank you a lot!!!!

Comment: Happy to help :-)